# General term for muggle-type terms?

Tags: terminology, offensive-language, pejorative-language, hypernyms, generic-term

Is there a general term to refer to "a semi-denigrating term used by a minority social group (not necessarily a racial group) to refer to the majority".  Examples would be "muggle", "gentile", "textile", "breeder", "straight", "mundane", "vanilla" etc.  (I am not referring to outright derogatory terms)

Comment: "Textile"? What is that from? As opposed to the minority "clothes made from animal skins"?

Comment: @MItch, "textile" = people who wear clothes

Comment: So from your examples, I might infer that you are a gay Jewish nudist wizard telepath with no children? :-) Great question! +1

Comment: @Kit +1 for using the word ... telepath (are you implying somebody here is a Homo Superior?)

Comment: Great question, but I'm not sure if there is an answer.

Comment: Some more examples: "mono" (-sexual, used by bisexuals), "normals" (various), "cis" (by transfolk).

Comment: @tchrist, Why is this thread "protected"? It doesn't even seem to have many views.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that groups of pejoratives are classified by scale (i.e. minority pejoratives; majority pejoratives) but these words and terms are relevant for the discussion:

- Descriptions of "the majority" include *the masses*; *sheep*; *common*; *pop*.
- "Reverse discrimination" is the concept of a retaliation against a [dominant or majority group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_discrimination) and includes subterms such as *reverse racism*
- "Affirmative action" is a classification of policies that are intended to react against an ill-founded majority
- An "exclusionist" is one who [advocates the exclusion](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exclusionist) of others; this could apply to certain groups against others (e.g. Jews and gentiles)

None of these are a perfect fit but it they may help with specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

you might be looking for the word [ethno-phaulisms](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ethnophaulism)

> ```
>   –noun
> ```
>
> 1. Creating negative cognitive images of a different group, negative
>   worth and/or caricatures (jokes having
>   to do with someone's features).
>      2. Using derogatory or disparaging words.

and example of this would be [hoi polloi](http://www.wordnik.com/words/hoi%20polloi)

> ```
>   –noun
> ```
>
> 1. The common people; the masses.
>
> *"Here and there, a gracious residence sat comfortably insulated by its wide grounds, a >    grand lady spreading her skirts, ignoring the presence of the hoi polloi nearby."
>      **— Drums of Autumn***

Comment: He's not asking for examples, but for a word for terms like `hoi polloi`. He's asking for a word for such words.

Comment: I think BlueWhale is looking for a term for the terms, not a term for the people.  Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a "meta-term"... a term which describes all the terms that are like that

Comment: @BlueWhale oh okay - I got it ;)

Comment: Note that the Greek word "hoi" means, basically, "the," so "the hoi polloi" is considered a solecism. (We disdain hoi polloi.)

Comment: +1 to The Raven for pointing out the redundant "the", and I shall be redundant (because of The Raven) never more ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pejorative is slightly more general (for instance, it includes words directed at things other than people), but includes all those examples.

Comment: Too general for what I'm asking for

Comment: @BlueWhale: Are you looking for a word for 'pejorative for the _majority_'?

Comment: @Mitch... semi-pejorative, not overtly so, and which is specific to the type of minority that uses the term

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could get was "defamation", which although is used to mean statements that project a negative image of a group, nation, etc. As well as a single person:

> Defamation—also called calumny, vilification, traducement, slander (for transitory statements), and libel (for written, broadcast, or otherwise published words)—is the communication of a statement that makes a claim, expressly stated or implied to be factual, that may give an individual, business, product, group, government, or nation a negative image.